# How to draw x and y axis in ggplot2 R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I'd like to draw x and y axis using ggplot2. I managed to draw x axis with a function: `fun = function{x} {x* 0 }`, but I don't know how to do the same with y axis. If I use built in functions that draw x and y axis, like for example: `theme(axis.line.x = element_line(...))`, then I get the lines to be outside the plot itself, but I need the axis to see where they intersect with other functions.
Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = 0)
```